# How to change the page header

Tags: theming

I would like to change the heading of a page. I've created a menu item as node/13/something, its name is Enquiries. The page is showing the same name of the menu item as heading. I would like to show a different heading like 'This is a test' for the page instead of Enquiries. I've

tried `hook_preprocess_page()` with that I could only change the meta tag title.

Any suggestion is helpfulll
[image]

Comment: Drupal version?

Comment: Post some screenshots of what your trying to solve. I'm not sure what your referring to.

Comment: @JimmyKo Version is 7

Comment: @duckx Added the screen shot.